# Displaying folder contents in c - Run time error

Tags: c, runtime-error, dirent.h

I'm trying to show what folder contains as an output. When I run this program in my harddisk after 1-2 minutes it crashes, beside of crashing part it works just fine. I dont know how I can prevent this. Can anyone help me ?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void showingFiles(DIR *, char *);

int main(void) {
    DIR *folder;
    char path[350];

    sprintf(path, ".");
    folder = opendir(path);
    showingFiles(folder, path);
    closedir(folder);
    printf("\n\nEnter a key to close this program ");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void showingFiles(DIR *currentFolder, char *path){
    struct dirent *nextFile;
    DIR *subFolder;
    char copyPath[350];
    strcpy(copyPath, path);
    while ((nextFile = readdir(currentFolder)) != NULL) {
        sprintf(copyPath, "%s//%s", path, nextFile->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", (*nextFile).d_name);
        if ((strcmp(nextFile->d_name, "..")) &&
            strcmp(nextFile->d_name ,".") &&
            (subFolder = opendir(copyPath)) != NULL) {
            deletingFiles(subFolder, copyPath);
        }
    }
    closedir(currentFolder);
}
```

Comment: Your debugging tools can. We expect a *specific* question, nothing like "this doesn't work, help me fix it." See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to formulate good questions.

Comment: okay thanks man i will check it out.But do you think any reasons why this is happening?

Comment: i ve solved the problem by changing sprintf(copyPath,"%s//%s",path,nextFile->d_name); into sprintf(copyPath,"%s\\%s",path,nextFile->d_name);    When i debugged it got a segmentation fault why did i get this fault so late i mean why i didnt get this error at the beginning?

Comment: in windows i should use '\\' instead of '//'  even i used '//' it didnt give me that error at the beginning. I should have got this error sooner shouldn't have i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems in your code that can explain the crash:

- the buffers used to store the complete pathnames pay be too short and you use an unsafe `sprintf` to construct them, potentially causing buffer overflows.
- you never close the `subFolder` directory handles that you open in the recursive function `showingFiles`, potentially running out of system handles.
- you do close the directory handle `currentFolder` in the function `showingFiles()`, but is is also closed in the `main()` function.  This causes undefined behavior.  As a rule of thumb, always close the handle in the function that opened it and only there.

Less important but issues:

- To name `showingFiles` a function that performs a recursive removal of a complete directory tree is a bit misleading.
- separating directory and pathnames with double slashes `//` is useless and not portable. You may have been thinking of `\\` and converted this Windows specific directory separator into `//` for Unix portability, but be aware that single forward slashes **are** supported by the Windows file system handlers, to you should always use `/` as a directory separator for programs aimed for both Unix and Windows.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void deleteTree(DIR *, const char *);

int main(void) {
    char path[350] = ".";
    DIR *folder = opendir(path);

    if (folder != NULL) {
        deleteTree(folder, path);
        closedir(folder);
    }
    printf("\n\nEnter a key to close this program ");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void deleteTree(DIR *currentFolder, const char *path) {
    char copyPath[1024];
    struct dirent *nextFile;
    DIR *subFolder;

    while ((nextFile = readdir(currentFolder)) != NULL) {
        snprintf(copyPath, sizeof(copyPath), "%s/%s", path, nextFile->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", nextFile->d_name);
        if (strcmp(nextFile->d_name,"..")
        &&  strcmp(nextFile->d_name,".")
        &&  (subFolder = opendir(copyPath)) != NULL) {
            deletingFiles(subFolder, copyPath);
            closedir(subFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when we use closedir(subFolder), do we also free(nextFile) ?
and would it make difference if we put closedir outside of loop like last statement of the function ?

Comment: `nextFile` must not be freed.  `closedir(subFolder);` must only be called if `opendir()` succeeded, so inside the `if` block. If you do not call `closedir()` there, the next `opendir()` will overwrite the `subFolder` variable, causing resource leakage.